# How to store the json data into an output array

Tags: ibm-midrange

I am consuming web and getting output in the json format of length 8 MB and storing it into the clob feild of length 8 MB.

Now i want to move the ouput from clob and store it into an array..

any suggestions on the possible options...

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and tell us what problems you have had.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.